# Do system(); commands work in exactly the same way as batch commands?

Tags: c++, windows, command-line, cmd

Basically, do all batch commands (normally executed in a batch file, or just typed in CMD) work within the system(); function? Are they the exact same processes, or is system(); based on the syntax of the CMD/batch commands?

Comment: On which operating system?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: "batch file" implies Windows. I'll fix the tags.

Comment: No, Linux has the `batch` command, which does accept files

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Just trust me on this. Or ask google.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: That's pretty strong language to defend a indefensible position.

Comment: `cmd` is the executable which interprets the `system()` string on Windows systems, and only on Windows systems (Well, also on Wine, but let's not carried away). It's definitely not Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the question in the title,

> **”** Do system(); commands work in exactly the same way as batch commands?

is "no".

But then in the main question text you clarify that by "batch commands" you include commands *typed* in the command interpreter, which is much like `system`. So then the answer is "yes", for that unorthodox & pretty meaningless meaning of "batch commands".

Regarding the "no" answer, for the question in the title, batch commands (in the sense of batch commands) are blocking for invocations of GUI subsystems programs, while typed commands are not. Testing this now, I found that `system` with g++ and Visual C++, is blocking for GUI programs. But this is not guaranteed. There are also syntactical differences. In particular that concerns the use of `%`.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity/consistency - I'm still getting to grips with this. Ignoring batch, anything that can be typed in the command prompt, can be typed in system();?

Comment: The `system` function calls the host's default command intepreter, with the specified command. In Windows that means `cmd.exe` is invoked, with the command as an argument. It can be an internal command if you want. E.g. you can try `dir & pause`. However, cmd.exe has lousy to non-existent quoting abilities, so when the command involves quotes you may not always be able to specify it as an argument, and hence, invoke it via `system`.

Comment: Would CMD.exe itself therefore be noted as a running process  when system() is called? My school has banned cmd.exe recently,  and the keywords CMD.exe are blocked and automatically close any application containing them. Network managers are also notified when CMD is being used. Does it invoke CMD.exe 'quietly' or is it completely activated when system() is used? (sorry if 'activated' is vague)

Comment: Yes, it's run. Sounds like you need a better school. But who doesn't.

Comment: Thank-you very much for all your help! :) It took them > 3 months to realise people were having 'shutting down wars' across the network, and even then, it was only because someone told them directly - I was hoping system(); would be a sneaky shortcut, but if they're informed of it's use then it won't work! :P

Comment: @DaPlayer99: Thanks for the information. I was not aware of the issue, that people could be as stupid as your school's IT staff. This means that I will prioritize first of all getting rid of `system` use for codepage handling in my work-in-progress [cppx library](https://github.com/alf-p-steinbach/cppx/blob/plutonium/os_specific/winapi/get_set_active_codepage.impl.hpp), for it would too bad if students at some schools couldn't use it.

Comment: Do you know any alternatives? and what will your project do? I'm intrigued!

Comment: Just for completeness, quote marks may also be treated differently in system() than in an interactively-typed command.  See `cmd /?` for a detailed description of what `cmd /c` does.  (The system() function *should* use the /S flag, but it doesn't.)

Comment: As for the school's setup, it depends on how they've implemented it whether system() will be affected.  Blocking cmd.exe completely, while possible, would seem likely to have some very nasty side-effects.  They've probably just used one of the built-in group policy settings, and I don't think system() will trigger that.  But I recommend against attempting to bypass policy.  Neither IT folk nor school boards are well-known for their tolerant, forgiving nature.

Comment: @HarryJohnston  I'm not planning on shutting down all computers at once,  or erasing the public drive or anything extreme like that, but I understand your point though. Me and a friend took a useful program that we had designed that would help the rest of the prefect team in the future deal with people mis-using the computers (basically a nicer looking GUI for the shutdown command, where you could select PCs etc) So I'm in the good books for using initiative to try and help prefects through this. I'm just curious if it's still be possible w/out CMD, that's why I posted.

Comment: @DaPlayer99: `shutdown` is an external command. On a typical computer with local Windows installation it's `C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe`. So you can invoke that directly via a Windows API function like `ShellExecute`.

Comment: Thanks very much - I'll take a look into that. I've got an exe ready on a penstick for tomorrow, that just opens 3 instances of notepad when you click enter (starting at the basics!) so if all goes to plan, that should be OK. Then I'll try to add in shutting down/other functions (and hopefully not get destroyed by IT technicians). Thanks again for all your help mate, I really appreciate it!